# Is compliment of a zero section of a vector bundle a submanifold?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, principal-bundles, submanifold, line-bundles

Let $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ be a smooth vector bundle. Let $S:M\rightarrow E$ be it's zero section. Let $M'=E-S(M)$.

**Is $M'$ a smooth submanifold  of $M$ ?**

It is clear that $S$ is a smooth injective immersion. So we know that $S(M)$ is a submanifold of $M$. I wanted to use this fact  to prove that $M'$ is a submanifold of $M$ but could  not proceed much.

In *Loop Spaces, Characteristic Classes and Geometric Quantization* by *Jean-Luc Brylinski* in the section 2.1 (classification of Line bundles) it is mentioned that given a complex line bundle $P:L\rightarrow M$ the corresponding principle $C^*$- bundle is $P':L^{+}\rightarrow M$ where $L^{+}$ = $L- \sigma(M)$ where $\sigma$ is the zero section of $P$ and $C^*$ is the non zero group of complex numbers under multiplication.

My question is **how do we know that $L^{+}$ is a submanifold of $L$ so that we can talk about principle bundle?**

Comment: In total generality, an open subset of a manifold is always a manifold.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes Sir.Thank you sir for the comment. I am aware of this fact. I was actually confused in proving $L^{+}$ is indeed an open subset of $L$. But now I got it. I wrote a simple answer for it below.

Comment: The short answer: Smoothness is a local property, and bundles are locally trivial. (Second-countability or similar is often also required, but that's easy to check.)

Comment: @anomaly Sorry I didn’t get .. Can you please elaborate how your comment is related to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch** Pick a local trivialization of $\pi : E \to M$, say, $\Phi : U \times \Bbb V \to \pi^{-1}(U)$, where $\Bbb V$ is a model fiber. Since $\{ 0 \}$ is closed in $\Bbb V$, $U \times \{0\}$ is closed in $U \times \Bbb V$ and $\Phi(U \times \{0\}) = \pi^{-1}(U) \cap S(M)$ is closed in $\Phi(U \times \Bbb V) = \pi^{-1}(U)$. Varying $U$ over a cover of $E$ by local trivializations we conclude that $S$ is closed in $E$, so $E \setminus S(M)$ is open in (and hence is a smooth submanifold of) $E$.

Comment: Thanks I got it. I wrote another answer to this question. Please check once at your leisure.

Answer (score 0):

An open subset of a manifold is a manifold, just take the intersections with the charts.

Comment: How do you know that the compliment of the zero section  is an open subset?

Comment: @Insearchforinfinity take a point in the complement. Then there is some family of open sets in M that trivializes the bundle, so the point lies in $\mathbb{R}^n\times U\setminus \{0\}\times U$, and our point has the form $(v,x)$. Take an open set $V$ about $v$ not containing zero, so that $V\times U$ contains our point and not the zero section. We can do this for all points, so our set is open.

Comment: thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let $l\in L^{+}$. Consider $\pi(l)\in M$. Let $(U,\phi)$ be a trivialization  around  $\pi(l)$. Hence $l\in \pi^{-1}(U)- \sigma(U) \subseteq L^{+}$ Now $\phi(\pi^{-1}(U)- \sigma(U))$ is diffeomorphic and hence homeomorphic to $J=(U \times C - U\times \lbrace 0\rbrace$) which is open in $U \times C$ as $U\times \lbrace 0\rbrace$ is closed in $U \times C$. As $\phi$ is a homeomorphism hence 
 ($\pi^{-1}(U)- \sigma(U)$) is an open subset of $\pi^{-1}(U)$ and hence an open subset of $L$ contained in $L^{+}$. Therefore  $l\in L^{+}$ is an interior point of $L^{+}$. But $l$ is an arbitrary point of $L^{+}$. Hence $L^{+}$ is an open subset of $L$ and hence an open submanifold of $L$. (Hence Proved)

**Alternatively it can be shown that the image set of any section of a vector bundle is a closed set in the the top space $L$**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98828/discussion-on-answer-by-in-search-for-infinity-is-compliment-of-a-zero-section-o).

Comment: Thanks, @AloizioMacedo.

Comment: Thanks @AloizioMacedo

Comment: @Travis I edited my answer.. Thanks for the discussion.